# c# WCF DataService client behavoir similar to BeforeSendRequest

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a WinForm client that its using WCF DataServices. I would like to know if WCF DataServices has some kind of BeforeSendRequest and AfterSendRequest so I can show on the UI an icon that some database request its running.

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WCF doesn't have anything like Global.asax where we can handle BeginRequest and EndRequest

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I guess the interface IClientMessageInspector will be handy.
The methods to be implemented will be BeforeSendRequest and AfterReceiveReply. I guess these are the two events you are looking for.

The documentation regarding this is available in the following msdn link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx

In short, you will have to implement the IClientMessageInspector( part of System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher) and also implement IEndpointBehavior (part of System.ServiceModel.Description) to hook the inspector on to the client endpoint. And thus change the configuration in the client endpoint to refer the endpoint behaviour that was added.